# Como retirar cabeçalho da tela em algumas rotas

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Bom dia pessoal, no meu projeto angular 4 completei a tela de adm e gostaria que o cabeçalho não aparecesse nela, sei que poderia fazer isso com o ngIf mas estou perdido >_>, Alguém pode dar uma luz?
O app module.html estar assim

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div style="padding-top:100px" class="container">
  <flash-messages></flash-messages>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você gostaria de remover o `<app-navbar>` ou o cabeçalho vem desse `<router-outlet>`?

Comment: gostaria de remover o <app-navbar>

Comment: Realmente a melhor opção nesse caso seria um `*ngIf`. Se você quer simplesmente sumir com ela sem dinamismo, pode colocar `<app-navbar *ngIf="true"></app-navbar>`. Agora se você quer que esse comportamento ocorra sempre que você faça uma ação você terá que em algum método alterar seu valor. Por exemplo, supondo que você tenha o método `(click)="mostrarCabecalho()"`, dentro desse método você deve setar uma outra variável, por exemplo `isCabecalho` que estará como `false` e passará para `true`. Essa variável deverá estar no seu cabeçalho, assim:  `<app-navbar *ngIf="isCabecalho"></app-navbar>`